# how to give focus for text box in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to focus a text box when user enter a wrong value .but i don't know how to add focus() in my code. any suggestion

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtfirstname" alt="spnfirstname" name="txtfirstname">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtmiddlename" name="txtmiddlename" alt="spnmiddlename">

$('document').ready(function () {
    $('#txtfirstname,#txtmiddlename,#txtlastname,#txtmothertongue,#txtplaceofbirth')
            .bind('keyup', function () {
                var theValue = $(this).val();
                var spanid = $(this).attr("alt");
                if (theValue != '' && theValue.match(/^[\a-zA-Z]+$/) == null)
                {
                    theValue = theValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z, ]/g, '')
                    $("#" + spanid).text("alphabets only");
                    $('#txtfirstname').focus();
                }
                else
                    $("#" + spanid).text(" ");
            });
});
```

Comment: You focus is working fine can you explain bit further what actually you wanna do?

Comment: i want to freeze the text box when wrong value entered. freeze until user enter correct value

Comment: like this $("#item_name").focus();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
theValue = theValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z, ]/g, '')
$("#" + spanid).text("alphabets only");
$(this).val(theValue);  <<== Add this
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
$('#txtfirstname').focus();  //Remove this one
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3vodognm/)**

Comment: its works perfectly on chrome but not woring in firfox

Comment: Click on demo link in `firefox` and check it work fine.

Comment: Might be your code issue this demo work in `firfox` and `chrome` both

Answer (score 0):

Listen to focusout event, check if the input is invalid then re focus it.

```
$('#txtfirstname').focusout(function(e) {
    if(invalidInput){
        $('#txtfirstname').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: where to add this function

Comment: Anywhere inside $('document').ready() 
Just replace invalidInput with something like

$(e.target).val().match(/^[\a-zA-Z]+$/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to give up the freeze. The trick is to prevent the typing event from happening, that way the value never changes unless you approve it.

I forked @Sadikhasan 's fiddle: **[Forked demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5rx9ac83/)**

One more thing, the `alt` attribute has a semantic value and should be in an `img` tag, you shouldn't use it like you have. If you still want to "reference" another element consider using the `data-*` attributes.